# My JTable is still editable when double-clicking after return isEditable to false?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Here is my code to update my table:

```
private void UpdateTable() {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM product";

    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs = pst.executeQuery();

    summaryproductTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
}
```

And this is the code that is generated by Netbeans(7.3.1), I've added the isEditable because I'm following the instruction that I found here in stackoverflow:

```
summaryproductTable = new javax.swing.JTable();

summaryproductTable.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 11)); // NOI18N

summaryproductTable.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
    new Object [][] {
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null}
    },
    new String [] {
        "type", "materialcode", "serialnumber", "status", "careof", "date", "name",        "accountnumber", "contactnumber"
    }
)
{public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column){return false;}}
);



summaryproductTable.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        summaryproductTableMouseClicked(evt);
    }
});

jScrollPane1.setViewportView(summaryproductTable);
```

*I just noticed through trial and error that the JTable is not editable but when you called the UpdateTable() method it become editable again.

Comment: You need to override the isCellEditable in whatever implementation ```DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs)``` returns.

Comment: I haven't use override in my entire programming life, how do I exactly do that?

Comment: Then it would be a good idea to begin with the basics.

Comment: That's what you do in the DefaultTableModel. When you implement a method which is already defined in the superclass(in your case isCellEditable), you're hiding the original implementation with your own(and returning false for every cell).

Comment: Guys please I need your help, how do I put that override thing?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html
You'll need to do that in that ```DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs)``` method

Comment: But that method is when I import net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils and by adding rs2xml.jar in my libraries

Comment: If you can't modify the source but need to use this method then you need to write a wrapper table model. If you don't know what that means or how to do this - sorry, you don't have the basic knowledge yet to fulfil the task.

Answer (score 0):

In NetBeans
right click on table -> properties -> editable is selected in checkbox
make it unselected
Simple....